# Receber valor do input e passar na URL

Tags: php

Preciso passar o valor selecionado em um datepicker do Bootstrap para a URL, mas quando clico pra executar, não acontece nada:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['start_range']))
    {
        $start_range = $_GET['start_range'];
        $end_range = $_GET['end_range'];
    }

?>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Inicial"  id="start_range" name="start_range" value="<?php echo $start_range ?>">
<input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Final"  id="end_range" name="end_range" value="<?php echo $end_range ?>"> 
<a href="?start_range=<?=$start_range?>&end_range=<?=$end_range?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">Ir</a>
```

Comment: "quando clico pra executar, não acontece nada:" - clica onde? na ancora que está no código? pode colocar o HTML renderizado também pf

Comment: Pode ser um problema com short tags. Experimente trocar `<?=$start_range?>` pela solução padronizada, que é `<?php echo $start_range; ?>` e `<?php echo $end_range; ?>`. Mas se o que vc quer é mudar o URL em tempo real, aí não pode ser por PHP, teria que usar JS para atualizar dinamicamente, pois o PHP roda antes da página ser enviada.

Comment: @Expl0it Coloque mais detalhes na sua pergunta, não da pra saber como você esta tentando fazer isso.

Comment: E sua pergunta é?

Comment: Expl0it na edição coloque apenas a pergunta, após votação para reabertura você pode adicionar uma resposta.

Comment: Como disse o @Orion, a pergunta deve ficar como estava, e a resposta postada ali embaixo, na área de respostas. Reverti a edição (mas você pode ver o que tinha postado no [histórico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/44214/revisions)). Também estou reabrindo a pergunta para que você possa adicionar a resposta, ok?

Answer (score 0):

*E lá vamos nós... (Bruxa da Vassoura, Pica-Pau)*

$_GET e $_POST são dois arrays superglobais que estão sempre disponíveis independente de escopo, isto é, ele estarão disponíveis dentro e fora de funções/métodos de classe sem você precisar fazer nada para poder utilizá-los.

Porém, apesar de sempre disponíveis eles apenas terão valores armazenados sob determinadas circunstâncias.

Se a Requisição for feita via POST, manualmente por um formulário que tenha o termo **post** definido em seu atributo **action**:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="name" value="John" />
    <input name="location" value="Boston" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Ou via AJAX **com** postagem de dados:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

**$_POST** será preenchido. A exemplos dos fragmentos de código acima, ao se depurar essa variável com [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) ou [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/var_dump) você teria:

array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "John" ["location"]=> string(6) "Boston" }

Já **$_GET**, além dos dois cenários acima expostos, porém com os atributos definidos como **GET** ao invés de **POST** também é populado com as *quesrystrings* definidas na URL.

*Querystrings*, a grosso modo são pares chave=valor que estejam presentes na URL quando do momento de sua execução. E múltiplos pares são separados pelo caractere **&** (*ampersand*):

```
http://www.site.com/index.php?name=John&location=Boston
```

Agora que tudo foi explicado, vamos chegar no seu problema.

Você quer que os dados que tenha trafegado via POST apareçam na URL. Na mesma Requisição, tanto quanto eu sei, apenas com PHP é impossível porque cada Requisição é configuarada e executada de um jeito diferente.

Porém, como pelo seu código me parece que está acontecendo uma paginação de resultados, torna-se possível pois a primeira Requisição pode trafegar via POST e as subseqüentes por GET.

Supondo que seja esse o cenário, seu código ficaria assim:

```
if( isset( $_POST['start_range'] ) ) {

    $start_range = $_POST['start_range'];

} else {

    $start_range = ( isset( $_GET['start_range'] ) ? $_GET['start_range'] : 10 );
}
```

Ou seja, se a Requisição feita vier por POST, a variável **$start_range** receberá o valor armazenado em $_POST (se houver).

Se a Requisição não for feita via POST, o `else` será analisado e, se o parâmetro existir na URL e consequentemente presente em $_GET, ele será usado.

Por fim, se tudo o mais falhar, definimos um valor padrão para não quebrar a lógica.

Seja onde for que você vá usar essa variável, basta ecoar seu valor, seja num campo de formulário, ou no atributo *href* de um link.

> A mesma explicação acima é válida para a variável **$end_range**